# Axios Interceptors 401 React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, interceptor

Hello can anyone help me, I have a problem about axios intercepotrs. When Error Status === 401 My Application (React Native) does not redirect to the signin page.

```
import axios from "axios";
import {BASE_URL} from '@env'
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const TOKEN_KEY = "token"
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL
})


api.interceptors.response.use(async (response) => {
    return response
  }, async function (error) {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 500) {
      api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''
      await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY)
      navigation.navigate('SignIn')
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

export {api}
```

Can anyone tell me how properly deal with the condition ?

Comment: Take a look that the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `useNavigation`, which is a hook, inside a function which is not a React component.

You can transform this into a custom hook or just use the interceptor inside your root (App.js) React component.

Comment: can you give me article or something to reference me, make custom hooks ?

Comment: Here you go: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks